# How extract the messages strings from a .net class to a resource?

Tags: c#, multilingual

I have my c# class file (.cs), and this have messages strings.

How to generate a resource file from the class file?

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for extracting strings to resource:

- [Resource Refactoring Tool](http://www.codeplex.com/ResourceRefactoring)

If you are looking for reading from the resource file:

- [.NET - Localization using Resource file](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Localization.aspx)
- [CSharp reading string from resource file](http://snipplr.com/view/2140/csharp-reading-string-from-resource-file--------------------/)

Comment: I am looking for massive extracting strings from a code file to a resource file. Exist?

Comment: The tool you recommend doesn't work with VS2010: use this one instead: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/39ae29d3-81e1-43d4-9c48-fc9644869d84

Answer (score 1):

Message strings are a UI implementation detail.  Consider an enum first.  Next, leverage Project + Properties, Resources tab to enter resource strings.